# Multidimensional Fourier Transform and Parseval's Identity

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $k=(k_1,k_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in [0,2\pi]^2$ and $F(\lambda)$ be a bounded real function of $\lambda\in [0,2\pi]^2$.

How do I prove the following equation?

$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)}\int_{[0,2\pi]}\sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty \lvert l\rvert \bigg\lvert\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{[0,2\pi]} e^{il\lambda_1 }F(\lambda)d\lambda_1 \bigg\rvert^2{d\lambda_2}\\
+\frac{1}{(2\pi)}\int_{[0,2\pi]}\sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty \lvert l\rvert \bigg\lvert\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{[0,2\pi]} e^{il\lambda_2 }F(\lambda)d\lambda_2 \bigg\rvert^2{d\lambda_1}
\\=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^2}|k_1|\bigg|\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{[0,2\pi]^2}e^{i(k_1\lambda_1+k_2\lambda_2)}F(\lambda)d\lambda\bigg|^2\\
\\+\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^2}|k_2|\bigg|\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{[0,2\pi]^2}e^{i(k_1\lambda_1+k_2\lambda_2)}F(\lambda)d\lambda\bigg|^2
$$

Comment: If $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ then things like $\lambda\in\theta^n$ and $\int_\theta$ make no sense. Did you maybe mean $\theta=[0,2\pi]$???